# Why has `whonix` gateway a full blown `kde` desktop?

Tags: whonix

Why is it that the gateway, that's just there to relay traffic in to and out of tor network, has a full blown kde desktop?

Is it possible to down-size it by 'apt-get purge kde-workspace' or are there any implications against?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that the gateway, that's just there to relay traffic in to and out of tor network, has a full blown kde desktop?

This is answered in [Whonix FAQ](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/FAQ#Graphical_Whonix-Gateway.3F).

> Is it possible to down-size it by 'apt-get purge kde-workspace' or are there any implications against?

This is answered in [Whonix documentation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Desktop_Environments).